# Missing "New" button on a custom related list

Tags: lightning, custom-object, related-list

I have a new custom object and it is related to Contact.  As an admin, the list of records and New button show.  But for a different user with a different profile and role the New button does not show.

In the Related List in Contact, Session has the New Standard Button selected to be displayed in the related list.

What needs to change to have the New button show?

Logged in as an Admin
[image: Logged in as an Admin]

Logged in as a different user and New button is missing.
[image]

Comment: Does the different user have "Create" access to the `Session` object?

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: go to the Profile for the user and look for Create permissions checked for `Session`

Comment: @SebastianKessel Thanks.  The user profile did not have the create set on the Object permission.